# Grouping and summing by Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

I would like to get the total order amount for each customer with Linq, I know I need to group and sum I have only succeeded to group without summing the whole amount for each order.

```
var OrderByCustumer = new[] {
        new { name = "cust1", order = 400 },
        new { name = "cust1", order = 250 },
        new { name = "cust1", order = 130 },
        new { name = "cust2", order = 30 },
        new { name = "cust3", order = 205}
     };
    
    var res= OrderByCustumer.GroupBy(x=>x.name).Select((x,y)=>new{
    a=x.Key
    });
    
    foreach(var a in res){
     Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
   

.**
OutPut
a = cust1 
a = cust2 
a = cust3
**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var res = OrderByCustumer.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(x => new {
    a = x.Key,
    sum = x.Sum(c => c.order)
});

foreach (var item in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ item.a} - Sum = {item.sum}");
}
```

Comment: It didn't work,

Comment: What exactly didn't work? doesn't `res` have sum property populated?

Comment: I got an error 'IGrouping<string,<anonymous type: string name, int order>>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload
'Queryable.Sum(IQueryable<int>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<int>'

Comment: @JaafarJaafar Try the updated answer

Comment: Thank you it works! , could you please explain your anwser more.

Comment: When we use `GroupBy`, we group the results based on a `key`. Here the key is name (customer). Once you group based on key, you can only do aggregation operations like Max, Min, Avg, Sum etc on the other values. So, here we chose `Sum` aggregation function on the order property.